# Diferencias entre usar while o read

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Buen día,

Tengo una duda, que diferencia tiene entre ejecutar mi código para saber si un registro existe con la sentencia While o solo con el Read. Que cambia entre estos dos factores? Hacen lo mismo? Dado mi código, hay algo que mejorar? Se que hago mal uso al no parametrizar la consulta, pero por los momentos lo voy a hacer de esa forma.

CON LA CONDICION READ

```
        cls_general myCls_general = new cls_general();

        myCls_general.conexion_mssql("1");

        mysqlcommand_select.Connection = myCls_general.myConnection;

        strSQL = " SELECT IdCliente, IdContactoAccionista " +
                 " FROM Accionistas " +
                 " WHERE IdContactoAccionista='" + accionista + "' AND IdCliente='" + cliente + "'";

        mysqlcommand_select.CommandText = strSQL;

        mySqlDatareader_select = mysqlcommand_select.ExecuteReader();

        try
        {
            if (mySqlDatareader_select.HasRows == true)
            {
                mySqlDatareader_select.Read();

                cls_MessageBox mensaje = new cls_MessageBox("6");
                XtraMessageBox.Show(mensaje).ToString();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            FlyoutMessageBox.Show("Se ha detectado una situación inesperada, comunicate con el administrador del sistema: error al consultar el contacto accionista.", "Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
        finally
        {
            mySqlDatareader_select.Close();
            myCls_general.cerrar_conexion();
        }
```

CON LA CONDICIÓN WHILE

```
        cls_general myCls_general = new cls_general();

        myCls_general.conexion_mssql("1");

        mysqlcommand_select.Connection = myCls_general.myConnection;

        strSQL = " SELECT IdCliente, IdContactoAccionista " +
                 " FROM Accionistas " +
                 " WHERE IdContactoAccionista='" + accionista + "' AND IdCliente='" + cliente + "'";

        mysqlcommand_select.CommandText = strSQL;

        mySqlDatareader_select = mysqlcommand_select.ExecuteReader();

        try
        {
             if (mySqlDatareader_select.HasRows == true)
           {
                while (mySqlDatareader_select.Read())

                {
                    cls_MessageBox mensaje = new cls_MessageBox("6");
                    XtraMessageBox.Show(mensaje).ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            FlyoutMessageBox.Show("Se ha detectado una situación inesperada, comunicate con el administrador del sistema: error al consultar el contacto accionista.", "Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
        finally
        {
            mySqlDatareader_select.Close();
            myCls_general.cerrar_conexion();
        }
```

Buen día,

Tengo una duda, que diferencia tiene entre ejecutar mi código para saber si un registro existe con la sentencia While o solo con el Read. Que cambia entre estos dos factores? Hacen lo mismo? Dado mi código, hay algo que mejorar? Se que hago mal uso al no parametrizar la consulta, pero por los momentos lo voy a hacer de esa forma.

Answer (score 0):

El objeto SqlDataReader nos va a devolver un conjunto de datos al que tenemos acceso en forma secuencial meadiante Read(); por eso lo típico es recorrer el conjunto de resultado con while de la forma:

```
while (mySqlDatareader_select.Read())
{
    // Para extraer cada celda de la línea leída lo puedes
    // hacer así.
    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", 
                      // Pos Col0 suponiendo tipo int 
                      mySqlDatareader_select.GetInt32(0),  
                      // Pos Col1 suponiendo tipo string
                      mySqlDatareader_select.GetString(1));
}
```

No se trata de que haya una diferencia entre while o read es que ambas se complementan y es la forma en la que se leen datos. Esto está pensado para cuando el volumen de datos que devuelve la consulta es gigantesco. Si lo que quieres es obtener el cuerpo de datos de una vez, lo suyo sería llenar un DataTable:

```
 mySqlDatareader_select = mysqlcommand_select.ExecuteReader();
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Load(mySqlDatareader_select);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu explicacion, entonces de la forma que tengo el while, está correcto? lo que hace en la cláusula if, es que si la consulta contiene resultado, muestra un msgbox diciendo que existe.

Comment: En resumen y para poder entender bien, siempre es de "buena práctica" recorrer una consulta select con while?

Comment: Es como cuando lees un archivo secuencialmente. O seas vas leyendo mientras que no llegues al final del archivo. Lo mejor es usar while y la condición.

Comment: En esto me podrás ayudar un poco más? Sigo sin entender muy bien. Si utilizo el While en ese código, el msgbox se repite muchas veces, al usar solo el reader, hace lo que necesito, que es avisar una sola vez que el registro existe.

Que estoy haciendo mal? En todas las consultas select que haga, debo usar el while?

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres mostrar un MessageBox cada vez que lees un registro?¿Qué sentido tiene?

Comment: El MessageBox le dice al usuario que el registro existe, por lo cual, luego limpio los campos y mantengo un Return para agregar otro o dejarlo hata ahí.

Comment: Tu pregunta era relativa a while/read y he dado una respuesta. Lo que pretendes no logro entenderlo y es por eso que no sé cómo ayudarte. Lo habitual, al menos lo que yo hago, llamo a un método que me devuelve un resultado y es entonces cuando tomo alguna acción. No en mitad de una consulta mientras estoy leyendo registro a registro. Si lo que quiero es saber si un registro existe hago un SELECT basándome en un ID único que me devolverá un resultado único si existe y por tanto no preciso del while y con un solo read obtengo el dato.

Comment: Perfecto! Me respondiste al final con lo que quería saber. Entonces solo uso el reader cuando se que únicamente me va a devolver una sola fila, ya que la consulta es prácticamente exacta. Sobre el MessageBox, si coloco un bool que me diga si es cierto o falso, en vez del msgbox, es mejor? Más abajo, fuera del While coloco algo estilo if (bool=true).... tal acción...